# How to make built app with icon?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm writing an OSX App and added an icon for it.

After building in Xcode, I can see the app with icon under Products folder, but when I RightClick->'Show in Finder', the built file is shown without icon. I want the built file to have an icon.

Comment: It should have the icon, how are you adding the icon?

Comment: @Vervious Yes I added, in Xcode I can see the app surly with icon under Products folder.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For Mac OS applications, you need to create an **.icns** file and include it in your **Info.plist** just like any other project.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Just change icon.png to icon.icns

Answer (score 0):

When I submit an icon image for my app, I never add the .icns extension. It is automatically assumed by the compiler. So for the icon file "icon.icns", simply enter "icon".