# NSUserNotification don't show application icon in notification

Tags: objective-c, macos, notifications, center, osx-mountain-lion

I made a simple application with sending notification, but icon of the application does not show in the notification. iconset attached to the project, with all resolutions.

In what could be the problem?

Comment: I found answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/11857147/1609475

Comment: You should answer your own question and mark it as accepted!