# Mountain Lion Notification Center - App icon not showing

Tags: cocoa, icons, nsnotificationcenter

I have an app that sends a notification. The application bundle has an icon but the icon is not shown in the notification; instead it shows the blank app icon. I haven't been able to find anyone else with this issue. Any ideas?

Thanks

Comment: Probably due to caching by OSX and/or NSUserNotificationCenter - see  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856766/osx-notification-center-icon/11857147#11857147

Comment: That was the issue. Thanks, you can post that as an answer and I'll accept if you want.

Comment: That's OK - I'd post an answer if I knew how to force those cached details to be cleared when you build in XCode - I've had similar problems with apps not being recognised properly right after building.

Comment: I rebooted and deleted the contents of ~/Library/Saved Application State. After that, my icon started showing up.

Comment: These devforums links on this other SO thread mentioned here solved my problem. For the record, I had moved an old version of my App in /Application. This is where Notification Center was "getting" the icon from, and this old version had a broken Icon (bad .iconset). Trashing this version and restarting the Notification Center fixed my problem!