# Add app icon to NSUserNotification

Tags: swift, macos, cocoa, swift2, nsusernotificationcenter

I am currently making an application that displays a notification to the user, however it does not show the application icon.

Here is my code:

```
func showNotification(message:String, title:String = "App Name") -> Void {
    let notification = NSUserNotification()
    notification.title = title
    notification.informativeText = message
    NSUserNotificationCenter.defaultUserNotificationCenter().deliverNotification(notification)
}

showNotification("\(song)\n\(artist)",title: "Now Playing")
```

How would I add my application icon to the notification?

**Edit:**

Here is my Application Icon Asset:

[image]

And here is my notification.

[image]

Comment: What does your notification look like now? Also, have you added all the different icon sizes ? (https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/MobileHIG/IconMatrix.html)

Comment: @shim Updated question.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856766/osx-notification-center-icon possible help?

Comment: Upgrading the build number worked, as that thread said. Thanks

Comment: Change build version. Change bundle identifier fixed it for me