# Cannot change Electron notification icon on left

Tags: javascript, html, notifications, electron

My application uses a separate hidden BrowserWindow to show a new notification.
The notification has 2 icons. I cannot edit the electron icon on the left, while the icon on the right kan be edited just fine.

[image: Notification]

How can I change the left icon?

I've tried changing the icon of the BrowserWindow and changing the icon of electron through the electron-packager.
I've also changed the favicon icon of the page spawning the notification, but to no avail.

I cannot find any other documentation regarding it even being possible to have 2 icons in a notification. By my knowledge it should be a native HTML5 Notification.

**Platform:** Mac OS X El Capitan

**Electron version:** 1.1.1

**Code used in renderer Javascript:**

```
const electron = require('electron');
const ipc = electron.ipcRenderer;

var Notification = window.Notification || window.mozNotification || window.webkitNotification;

require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('showNotification', (event, message) => {
  Notification.requestPermission();
  var notification = new Notification("New Notification found");
});

require('electron').ipcRenderer.on('showNotificationAmount', (event, message) => {
  Notification.requestPermission();
  var notification = new Notification("New Notifications found!", {icon: "http://orig07.deviantart.net/d754/f/2011/132/e/4/google_chrome_icon_yellow_by_cameronsagey-d3g75gy.png", body: message + " new notifications available for you!"});
});
```

**Code used in Main.js:**

```
//Make hidden window, used for notifications
  hiddenNotificationBalloonWindow = new window({
      show: false,
      transparent: true,
      icon: nativeImage.createFromPath(__dirname + '/images/logowindowicon.png')
  });
  hiddenNotificationBalloonWindow.setRepresentedFilename(__dirname + '/images/logowindowicon.png');
  hiddenNotificationBalloonWindow.setDocumentEdited(true);
  hiddenNotificationBalloonWindow.loadURL("file://" + __dirname + "/windows/hiddenHTML5NotifyBalloonActivator.html");
```

Thanks for the help in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After reading through this: [OSX Notification Center Icon](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11856766/osx-notification-center-icon)

I noticed that adding a app-bundle-id through electron-packager fixed the issue for me. 
The issue was caused by icon caching in Mac OS X. Simply deleting the cache files did not solve the issue for me. Changing/adding a bundle-id did though.