# OSX: NSUserNotification - Displays old app icons.

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, nsnotifications

I am updating my build with a new UI and I changed the app icons. However when testing and running the new .dmg installs, the notifications keep displaying the old app icon.

Is there a way to clear the cache?

Comment: Related?  http://stackoverflow.com/q/11856766/2415822

Comment: That does not work. Also looking to implement this in code. Updating my app I cant tell a user to manually go delete a .db

Comment: @mKane did you got any solution ?

Comment: Yes but using a private api.

Comment: @mKane Which private api you used for that ?

Answer (score 0):

I think you can solve this by incrementing the Build number in the General section for the build Target. It worked for me :)

Comment: Notifiation icon cache does not get cleared with incrementing build numbers.. Changing the product ID does but I dont want to do that

Answer (score 0):

OS X apps typically contain multiple app icons which are used in different contexts (one for the App Store listing, one for Spotlight search, etc.)... have you done a search in the build directory to ensure that you don't have any only icons lingering in there?

I've had this issue before when I quickly removed the previous icons and added the updated ones but forgot to add all the sizes (thus it used the previous one for specific cases like notifications either because it was cached or still in the build folder);

Comment: I am sure. However the names of the icon.png remain the same. Its definitely a system caching problem. if I run a remove command from the terminal on the system cache all works great. But It shoudnt have to be re run every icon update. The dock updates great and so does the menu icons

Answer (score 0):

What fixed this for me on 10.14 was to delete DerivedData:

`rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData`